# Prevent people from accessing sites they shouldn't see via entering my server IP (Apache on Debian)

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, website

I have an Apache server running on Debian 8. I have successfully configured my domain, a virtual host, and letsencrypt, but I couldn't find a good solution to the following issue.

My relevant folder looks like this:

[image: Folder view on the server side / SCP tool]

When I browse my server IP in the browser, I get an overview (Index of/), like in the following picture:

[image: Folder view in the web browser]

I don't want people to be able to see this by browsing my IP address. If people browse by domain name, they get forwarded to the correct folder with the virtual host, so this is working. Now I could place an empty index.html into the parent folder. However, then people cann still browse IP/webalizer/ and then they are able to see website statistics which they should not be able to see.

What is the best way to solve my issue?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-direc

Comment: Thanks this helped for the first issue, not seeing a directory. But people can still access IP/webalizer and then see my server access statistics. How can I prevent that if I don't want to delete that webalizer folder or if I want to keep logging for my own use

Comment: Put a zero byte `index.html` in that directory.

Comment: Please, explain more detailed about you mean "see my server access statistics". Are you asking about blocking access to `webalizer` folder content?

Answer (score 1):

There are heaps of ways of dealing with this, including:

- Change the `DocumentRoot` location for the default host (not sure why this is `/var/www` - it is typically `/var/www/html`).
- Set up IP and/or password restrictions for `/var/www`.
- Set up redirection for the default host.

Answer (score 0):

> When I browse my server IP in the browser, I get an overview (Index of/)[.] I don't want people to be able to see this by browsing my IP address.

This is a use-case for `Options`, specifically `Options -Indexes`e.g.:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

This will return a `403 Forbidden` when accessing the specified directory or any sub-directory (assuming there is no e.g. `index.html` or you aren't accessing a named file directly e.g. `some-page.html`). You would place this `<Directory>` statement (or *ex.* `Options -Indexes`) wherever you have defined your `DocumentRoot` of `/var/www`. Note, however, this can be potentially overridden elsewhere. So while this is probably the "canonical" solution, it may not be the best one.

> Now I could place an empty index.html into the parent folder. However, then people can still browse `IP/webalizer/` and then they are able to see website statistics which they should not be able to see.

As alluded to in the other answer to this question, the real answer is simply not to have `Webalizer` in a web-accessible folder (i.e. not it `/var/www` if you are using that as your primary Apache `DocumentRoot`). If you wanted to view stats easily, you could have those stats produced in a folder that was only accessible via e.g. `localhost` or an internal network IP address. If you *had* to have it available via the web, then that directory should be protected with [Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html).